# Extract Certified users in Excel sheet in Moodle

Tags: moodle

> In the certificates page, I can extract the certified users into an
> Excel sheet, but I need to change the certificate code in the
> Certified user table with the course name or add the course name to
> the table.

[The Certified users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAccr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want the SQL with the course name?

```
SELECT u.id AS userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email,
        cc.id AS customcertid, cc.name AS customcertname,
        c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
        cci.timecreated AS timeawarded
FROM mdl_customcert_issues cci
JOIN mdl_customcert cc ON cc.id = cci.customcertid
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = cc.course
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = cci.userid
ORDER BY u.lastname, u.firstname, cc.name, c.fullname
```

Comment: when I download the certificate-issued users, the Excel sheet does not have the course name and I want to add it in the extracted fields.